# Converting UTC date time to a time in the future, considering daylight savings time of a time zone

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

We have a system that represents weeks with UTC times representing begin & end date times from the America/Chicago time zone.  Weeks start at midnight on Saturday morning central time and end at 23:59:59 on Friday evening central time, so their UTC entries in the database are:

```
Week 1 - begin: 2015-10-24 05:00:00, end 2015-10-31 04:59:59
Week 2 - begin: 2015-10-31 05:00:00, end 2015-11-07 05:59:59
Week 3 - begin: 2015-11-07 06:00:00, end 2015-11-14 05:59:59
Week 4 - begin: 2015-11-14 06:00:00, end 2015-11-21 05:59:59
Week 5 - begin: 2015-11-21 06:00:00, end 2015-11-28 05:59:59
```

So from the above examples of the weeks, you can see the time change from daylight to standard time reflect between 10/31 & 11/7.

I am needing to return N weeks from a given week.  Our systems are C# Azure worker & web roles, and run in the Azure cloud (all compute nodes are UTC).  My logic is to, take the starting week, and add N weeks work of days to the start date/time of the week and ask for weeks that have a start date greater than the original start date, and less than or equal to the calculated future date.

```
var weeks = repository.Fetch(x => x.BeginDate <= nWeeksAheadUtc && x.BeginDate > week.BeginDate)l=;
```

This works except when a change for daylight savings occurs within the resulting answer.  Because of the time change, asking for the next 3 weeks from Week 1 based on adding 21 days to Week 1's start date only results in Week 2 & 3 being returned, because the calculated future value is 2015-11-14 05:00:00, which excludes Week 4.

I have solved the problem using Nodatime in the following manner:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(week.BeginDate);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.InZoneStrictly(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["UTC"]);
zonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.WithZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Chicago"]);
DateTime centralDateTime = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
DateTime futureDateTime = centralDateTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(weekCount*7));
localDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(futureDateTime);
zonedDateTime = localDateTime.InZoneStrictly(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Chicago"]);
DateTime nWeeksAheadUtc = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc();

var weeks = repository.Fetch(x => x.BeginDate <= nWeeksAheadUtc && x.BeginDate > week.BeginDate).OrderBy(x => x.RetailerWeekNumber).ToList();
```

While it functions, it seems cumbersome and not very intuitive to developers that would follow me in maintaining this code.  Is there a cleaner way to do this via the Nodatime API or (base C# date/time) that I am missing?

**Adding in the requested example** - I just created a UnitTest project for this and these three classes:

Week.cs

```
using System;

namespace NodaTimeTest
{
    public class Week
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

WeekService.cs

```
using NodaTime;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace NodaTimeTest
{
    public class WeekService
    {
        private readonly List<Week> repository;

        public WeekService()
        {
            this.repository = this.InitWeeks();
        }

        public List<Week> GetNextWeeks(int weekId, int weekCount)
        {
            Week week = this.repository.First(x => x.Id == weekId);

            // the meat - how to do this the right way?
            LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(week.BeginDate);
            ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.InZoneStrictly(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["UTC"]);
            zonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.WithZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Chicago"]);
            DateTime centralDateTime = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
            DateTime futureDateTime = centralDateTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(weekCount * 7));
            localDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(futureDateTime);
            zonedDateTime = localDateTime.InZoneStrictly(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Chicago"]);
            DateTime nWeeksAheadUtc = zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc();

            var weeks = repository.Where(x => x.BeginDate <= nWeeksAheadUtc && x.BeginDate > week.BeginDate).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();

            return weeks;
        }

        private List<Week> InitWeeks()
        {
            // sets up our list of 10 example dates in UTC encompassing America/Chicago daylight savings time change on 11/1
            // this means that all weeks are 168 hours long, except week "4", which is 169 hours long.
            var weeks = new List<Week>();
            DateTime beginDate = new DateTime(2015, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                DateTime endDate = beginDate.AddDays(7).AddSeconds(-1);

                if (endDate.Date == new DateTime(2015, 11, 7, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc))
                {
                    endDate = endDate.AddHours(1);
                }

                weeks.Add(new Week { Id = i, BeginDate = beginDate, EndDate = endDate });

                beginDate = endDate.AddSeconds(1);
            }

            return weeks;
        }
    }
}
```

WeekServiceTest:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Linq;

namespace NodaTimeTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class WeekServiceTest
    {
        private readonly WeekService weekService = new WeekService();

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestGetNextThreeWeeksOverDaylightTimeChange()
        {
            var result = this.weekService.GetNextWeeks(2, 3);

            Assert.AreEqual(3, result.ElementAt(0).Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(4, result.ElementAt(1).Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(5, result.ElementAt(2).Id);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestGetNextThreeWeeksWithNoDaylightTimeChange()
        {
            var result = this.weekService.GetNextWeeks(5, 3);

            Assert.AreEqual(6, result.ElementAt(0).Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(7, result.ElementAt(1).Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(8, result.ElementAt(2).Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are saving UTC? According to the National Hurricane Center "The switch to daylight saving time does not affect UTC.".

Comment: +Kevin Yes, it is UTC.  While UTC does not reflect daylight savings time changes, the times represented (the length of the "week" in hours) does, because it's based on times in the central time zone, which is affected by daylight savings time changes.  Effectively, in the spring the week is shortened by one hour, and in the fall the week is lengthened by one hour, as you can seen in my example data quoted.

Comment: @MattJohnson: I'm genuinely unsure about putting this on Code Review. Given that we ask people to show what they've come up with so far, it feels like if there's code the "just about works, but really isn't nice" that shouldn't require going to CodeReview. The basis of this question is "How should I achieve X?" rather than "Please review my code which does X." But as I say, I'm in two minds...

Comment: @MattJohnson "_belongs on Code Review_" is not a valid close reason.

Comment: @JonSkeet There's no reason it can't be on both sites if it's posited correctly on both.

Comment: This may be on-topic for [codereview.se], if **A** the code works, **B** is not hypothetical or incomplete in any way

Comment: I think it's on-topic for code review - but yes, it feels like it's on-topic here too.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan dupes over multiple sites are generally frowned upon

Comment: @IceBox13, if you're looking for a review of your code, [codereview.se] might be the place to take this, but if you're looking more for a way to implement this via the Nodatime API or base methods, then Stack Overflow is the place for that

Comment: Could you clarify what is in the repository? If you could provide a short but complete example (with sample data in a list) that would be really useful. I'm pretty sure I have a good idea about how to do this better though.

Comment: (And also, please be clear about what `week.BeginDate` is... what is its Kind?)

Comment: I'm not looking for a review of my code.  I'm specifically asking how to use the Nodatime API to solve this problem properly.  While my code functions, I do not believe it to be a satisfactory solution, as I don't believe I've used Nodatime as the author intended.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - the Kind is UTC.  We use Fluent NHibernate and the mapper for the dates uses the CustomType<UtcDateTimeType> so that the hydrated DateTime instances are Utc kind.  I am working on a standalone example that I will add to the question.

Comment: Okay - see whether my answer does what you want.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I added in the example to the original question.  I'm going to examine your snippet below and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to offend anyone.  I was under the impression that code on StackOverflow should have a *problem* that needs resolving.  I've seen multiple other posts that were closed because the post only contained working code.  I supposed this post could be considered #4 on [the on-topic list](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but the criteria seems subjective.  I guess the question is - are posts that just ask "is there a better way to do this" on topic?  I'll ask on meta as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, no need to ask on meta.  I see that [this excellent guide](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23691) clarifies that it could be considered on topic here.  In the criteria chart, this one falls under "questions with a specific goal" - IMHO.  Thanks for the feedback everyone.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, if I've understood you correctly, I think you probably want something like:

```
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Chicago"];
var instantStart = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(week.BeginDate);
var chicagoStart = instantStart.InZone(zone);
var localEnd = chicagoStart.LocalDateTime.PlusWeeks(weekCount);
var chicagoEnd = localEnd.InZoneLeniently(zone);
var bclEnd = chicagoEnd.ToDateTimeUtc();

var result = repository
    .Fetch(x => x.BeginDate >= week.BeginDate && x.BeginDate < bclEnd)
    .OrderBy(x => x.RetailerWeekNumber)
    .ToList();
```

Note that I've made the lower bound *inclusive* and the upper bound *exclusive* - that's typically the simplest way to do things.

You could of course chain a lot of this together if you really wanted to:

```
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Chicago"];
var bclEnd = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(week.BeginDate)
    .InZone(zone)
    .LocalDateTime
    .PlusWeeks(weekCount)
    .InZoneLeniently(zone)
    .ToDateTimeUtc();
```

EDIT: The above is if your `BeginDate` is really the instant from which you want to start getting data. It sounds like in reality, you want to add a week to that to start with. At that point it would be:

```
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/Chicago"];
var instantNow = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(week.BeginDate);
var chicagoNow = instantStart.InZone(zone);
var localStart = chicagoNow.LocalDateTime.PlusWeeks(1);
var localEnd = localEnd(weekCount);
var bclStart = localStart.InZoneLeniently(zone).ToDateTimeUtc();
var bclEnd = localEnd.InZoneLeniently(zone).ToDateTimeUtc();

var result = repository
    .Fetch(x => x.BeginDate >= bclStart && x.BeginDate < bclEnd)
    .OrderBy(x => x.RetailerWeekNumber)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Yesterday when I was trying to do the calculations, I was adding days and coming up an hour short on the time change.  It looks like adding weeks handles that scenario better.  I have replaced my code with the second snippet with the fluent chain.  I did have to keep my lambda expression the way it was get the next n weeks excluding the starting weeks.  All my unit tests pass - thank you for your help!

Comment: @IceBox13: Adding days should have worked fine, so long as you were adding them to the `LocalDateTime`. If you really need to use an exclusive lower bound and an inclusive upper bound, that's very worrying... I'm not sure what you mean by "excluding the starting weeks" but it sounds like maybe you just need to add a week to the start first (in the same way).

Comment: meaning the original week shouldn't be part of the result set.  Starting with week 4, give me the next 3 weeks, and that should provide weeks 5, 6, & 7.  You keep talking about changing the bounds of my expression, which wasn't the core issue I had.  I'm always open to learning more - do you have an article or a principle/pattern to point me at so that I can understand why you feel so strongly about how the bounds are coded?

Comment: @IceBox13: In that case, the existing code is already broken, because anything *just a bit into* week 4 will still be returned. It really is part of the core issue :) Will edit the answer a bit. I don't think I've got an article about this, but maybe I should write one...

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow what you mean by "just a bit" into week 4.  The service method I'm working on doesn't allow for the input of an arbitrary date - it takes as input the ID of the week the client is referencing, and is asking for the next n consecutive week occurrences.  The method first fetches the referenced week, and then uses the fetched week's BeginDate as the starting point for the next query.  The BeginDate for any week will never be "just a bit" into the week.

Comment: @IceBox13: Do you mean every point of your data (as well as your query) is guaranteed to be aligned on a week boundary? That's pretty odd, but it would explain the problem. Still, I would make the query say what you *really* want it to say. For example, if you were querying numbers and you wanted "at least five, no more than 7" you wouldn't say "> 4, <= 6.99999". You'd say ">= 5, < 7". Aside from anything else, that means if `BeginDate` (in the data you're querying) every *does* start having more precision than "week", you'll still get the right results.